# Stored Procedure-SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Question: Write a stored procedure which accepts the camperid, category, chargedate, and amount as input parameters and has one output parameter which is of type varchar2 which will contain a message. o If the camperID is not a valid camperID the output parameter should be set to 'ERROR: No such camper ID.' o If the category is not a valid category the output parameter should be set to 'ERROR: No such charge category.' o If the Amount is not in the correct range the output parameter should be set to 'ERROR: amount must be >0 and no more than $ 40.' o If the Amount would cause the total spent to be more than the budget for that camper the output parameter should be set to 'ERROR: insufficient funds.'
Here is my query

```
create or replace procedure P_STORED
       (c_camperid in charges.camperid%type,c_category in charges.camperid%type, c_chargedate in charges.camperid%type, c_amt in charges.camperid%type,
        c_message   out varchar2  )
     as
       p_camperid   charges.camperid%type;
       c_cat charges.category%type;
       a_amt charges.amt%TYPE;
       c_date charges.chargedate%type;
       p_error varchar2(5);
       begin
       v_error := 'False';
       select c.camperid, c.category
        into p_camperid, c_cat
       from charges c
      where c.camperid = c_camperid;
      if p_camperid = c.camperid then
       v_error := 'true';
     c_message := 'Camper ' || c_camperid || ' exists';
     else
     v_error := 'False';
     c_message := 'Error: no such camper ID (' || c_camperid || ')';
     end if;
     if c_cat = c.category then
     v_error := 'true';
     c_message := 'Category ' || c_cat || ' exists';
     else
     v_error := 'False';
     c_message := 'Error: no such charge category (' || c_cat || ')';
      end if;
      if(a_amt >0 and a_amt < 40) then
       v_error := 'true';
     c_message := 'Amount ' || a_amt|| ' is with in range';
     else
     v_error := 'False';
     c_message := 'amount must be >0 and no more than $ 40.';
     end if;
     if(campers.spent < campers.budget) then
     c_message := 'Amount ' || a_amt|| ' is under budget';
     else 
     c_message := 'ERROR: insufficient funds';
     end;
```

I get this error
LINE/COL  ERROR

---

41/5      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:     if
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: You didn't show what preceded the 'as'.  Your 'into' targets are the same as the column name.  Oracle may accept local vaiables with the same name as columns, but it is bad practice as it confuses the developer.  Name your local variables and parameters so that they are easily recognizable as such.  Your 'IF' statement is invalid.  Look closely at what you are trying to compare -

Comment: Try to decompose your task into several steps, each of which would perform some **meaningful** operation and build your code from this code blocks. Because current code has a lot of syntax and styling errors and a bunch of unused variables.

Comment: I had extra input parameters because I also was trying to do to If the category is not a valid category the output parameter should be set to 'ERROR: No such charge category.' and o If the Amount is not in the correct range the output parameter should be set to 'ERROR: amount must be >0 and no more than $ 40.'

Answer (score 0):

Why would you pass the whole bunch of parameters when all you need is a camper ID (and there's nothing you'd do with the rest of them)? That just doesn't make sense ...

Here's an option which shows how to do it.

Sample table:

```
SQL> select * from charges;

  CAMPERID CATEGORY   CHARGEDATE                 AMT
---------- ---------- ------------------- ----------
         1 Category 1 12.10.2021 00:00:00        500

SQL>
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2    (par_camperid   in charges.camperid%type,
  3     par_message   out varchar2
  4    )
  5  as
  6    l_camperid   charges.camperid%type;
  7  begin
  8    select c.camperid
  9      into l_camperid
 10      from charges c
 11      where c.camperid = par_camperid;
 12
 13    par_message := 'Camper ' || par_camperid || ' exists';
 14  exception
 15    when no_data_found then
 16      par_message := 'Error: no such camper ID (' || par_camperid || ')';
 17  end;
 18  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    l_msg varchar2(100);
  3  begin
  4    p_test(1, l_msg);
  5    dbms_output.put_line(l_msg);
  6  end;
  7  /
Camper 1 exists

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> declare
  2    l_msg varchar2(100);
  3  begin
  4    p_test(2, l_msg);
  5    dbms_output.put_line(l_msg);
  6  end;
  7  /
Error: no such camper ID (2)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Code you wrote:

- typos, typos, typos ... is it `p_error` or `p_erorr`?
- `if` should have `end if`
- `if` can't contain a `select` statement (you have to select value separately, and then use it in `if`)
- `where` condition is wrong. Never, ever name parameters the same as column names. This: `where camperid = camperid` is equal to `where 1 = 1` and you'd get all rows from the table, not just the one you're looking for

Comment: I had extra input parameters because I also was trying to do to If the category is not a valid category the output parameter should be set to 'ERROR: No such charge category.'

Answer (score -1):

Without table definitions (ddl) and sample data it is difficult to address your issues. From your description and code it appears you have a single table; but *reading* from a design perspective I *see* at least 3 tables. You have a long way to go. In the following I will essentially just annotate your code (with some format changes, but only format, and of the the annotations). I will then show one on many possible solutions, keeping the code as succinct as possible.

```
create or replace 
procedure p_stored(                                   -- Bad name. Name should indicate what the procedure does.
          c_camperid   in charges.camperid%type
        , c_category   in charges.camperid%type
        , c_chargedate in charges.camperid%type
        , c_amt        in charges.camperid%type
        , c_message   out varchar2
        )
as  
    -- what do the various prefix values mean. Would be better (IMHO) to have a single 
    -- prefix indicating the use/location. My preference is l_ for local variables
    p_camperid   charges.camperid%type;
    c_cat        charges.category%type;
    a_amt        charges.amt%TYPE;
    c_date       charges.chargedate%type;
    p_error      varchar2(5);
          
begin
    v_error := 'False';              -- v_error not defined. Do you mean p_error? 
                                     -- really does not matter As it is not used other 
                                     -- setting its value ( multiple times) 
    select c.camperid, c.category
      into p_camperid, c_cat
      from charges c
     where c.camperid = c_camperid;
      
    if (p_camperid = c.camperid) then  -- this would always be true, if not Oracle would have  thrown   
       v_error := 'true';              -- a no_data_found exception on above select. that is if it were valid - it is not 
       c_message := 'Camper ' || c_camperid || ' exists';
     else
       v_error := 'False';
       c_message := 'Error: no such camper ID (' || c_camperid || ')';
    end if;
     
     if c_cat = c.category then        -- invalid refrence to table c.xxx does not exist after the Select 
        v_error := 'true';
        c_message := 'Category ' || c_cat || ' exists';
     else
        v_error := 'False';
        c_message := 'Error: no such charge category (' || c_cat || ')';
      end if;
      
    if (a_amt >0 and a_amt < 40) then               -- a_amt never populated so it is NULL 
        v_error := 'true';
        c_message := 'Amount ' || a_amt|| ' is with in range';
     else                                           -- because a_amt is null code falls into here every time
        v_error := 'False';
        c_message := 'amount must be >0 and no more than $ 40.';
     end if;
     
     -- on if below 
     --  Cannot refer to a table_name.column_name Those values need to be: 
     --   defined in the procedure
     --   populated via select or value set via assignment
     --   same applies above to c.xxx references above 
     -- Even so the comparision does NOT reference the amount value
     --   so if spent=50 and budget=100 and amount = 200 your test passes 
     if (campers.spent < campers.budget) then       
         c_message := 'Amount ' || a_amt|| ' is under budget';   -- if all syntax/logic errors/ corrected   
                                                                -- so evetything is valid you get this message every time.
     else 
         c_message := 'ERROR: insufficient funds';
     end;                                    -- add an end if before here. must terminate the last if statement.
```

Now a possible rewrite keeping the assumption that everything necessary exists in this single table. Probably/hopefully a bad assumption, but it can be worked with.

```
create or replace 
procedure validate_camper(
          p_camperid   in charges.camperid%type
        , p_category   in charges.camperid%type
        , p_chargedate in charges.camperid%type
        , p_amt        in charges.camperid%type
        , p_message   out varchar2
        )
as  
    -- define user exceptions 
    e_no_category      exception; 
    e_amt_range        exception; 
    e_budget_violation exception; 
    
    -- local constants
    k_nl constant varchar2(2) := chr(13) || chr(10);  -- New_Line: or as appropriate for your OS
    
    -- locak variables 
    l_charges_rec  charges%rowtype; 

begin  
    select *
      into l_charges_rec
      from charges c
     where c.camperid = p_camperid;

     if p_category  <>  l_charges_rec.category then
        raise e_no_category;
      end if;
      
    if p_amt < 0 or p_amt > 40 then
       raise e_amt_range;      
     end if;
     
     if l_charges_rec.spent + p_amt > l_charges_rec.budget then
        raise e_budget_violation; 
     end if;

    p_message := 'Camper Valid: No errors detected.';      
     
exception 
    when no_data_found then 
         p_message := 'Error: No such camper ID (' || p_camperid || ')';
         
    when e_no_category then 
         p_message := 'Error: No such charge category (' ||  p_category  || ')';   
    
    when e_amt_range then 
         p_message := 'Error: Amount must be >0 and no more than $ 40.';

    when e_budget_violation then 
         p_message := 'Error: Insufficient funds';
    
    when others then 
         dbms_output.put_line('Unexpected Error=>' || k_nl 
                              || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack); --  better write to Error_Log table 
         raise_application_error(-20199
                                ,'Fatial Error occured in validate_camper.'   -- Process failed do not hide that from user
                                  || k_nl || 'Process Unsuccessful'           -- or just raise to show actual error   
                                );
end validate_camper;
```

You may wish to read up on Oracle [user defined exceptions](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exceptions/named_prog.php).  
I realize this is a homework assignment (at least hopefully) and you need to write a procedure. However, just to point out with proper Primary key, Foreign key, and Check constraints defined at the table level this can all be done without any additional code. I will leave those for you to investigate. (Hint: 3 tables).  

**Note:** Not tested.